# need help displaying grouped xml data on .xaml in groups

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

Here is the basic xml..

> ```
> <events>
>  <eventday>
>   <eventdate>Date of events group 1</eventdate>
>    <eventsonday>
>     <eventitem>
>      <eventtime>Time of event 1</eventtime>
>      <eventtitle>Title of event 1</eventtitle>
>      <eventlocation>Location of event 1</eventlocation>
>     </eventitem>
>     <eventitem>
>      <eventtime>Time of event 2</eventtime>
>      <eventtitle>Title of event 2</eventtitle>
>      <eventlocation>Location of event 2</eventlocation>
>     </eventitem>
>    </eventsonday>
>   </eventday>
>   <eventday>
>   <eventdate>Date of events group 2</eventdate>
>    <eventsonday>
>     <eventitem>
>      <eventtime>Time of event 3</eventtime>
>      <eventtitle>Title of event 3</eventtitle>
>      <eventlocation>Location of event 3</eventlocation>
>     </eventitem>
>     <eventitem>
>      <eventtime>Time of event 4</eventtime>
>      <eventtitle>Title of event 4</eventtitle>
>      <eventlocation>Location of event 4</eventlocation>
>     </eventitem>
>    </eventsonday>
>   </eventday>
> </event>
> ```

I want to display the data in the same manner that the windows phone calendar (agenda view) is displayed.

**Thursday, January 5, 2012**

```
time of event 1
title of event 1
location of event 1

time of event 2
title of event 2
location of event 2
```

**Friday, January 6, 2012**

```
time of event 3
title of event 3
location of event 3

time of event 4
title of event 4
location of event 4
```

I don't think I'm parsing the data correctly, or have the .xaml set up correctly.  I'm thinking it needs to be set to bind the data in a stackpanel within a Listbox, but the < eventdate > group name is confusing me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create class hierarchy that represents xml file, and parse xml data to it.

For UI, use `LongListSelector` control from `Silverlight Toolkit`. [LongListCollection](https://github.com/Windcape/Diverse/blob/master/LongListSample/LongListCollection.cs) helps you with grouping events by date.

Usage:

```
 var list = new LongListCollection<Event, string>(Events, x => x.Date.ToLongDateString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I did a lot of research on this topic and using the LongListSelector seems to be the way to go.  I have also cleaned up my xml, that made all the difference.